# python API request for DYDX exchange not sending back a response in the terminal of Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, api, visual-studio-code

in visual studio code, I'm not getting a response back in the terminal.

I have no clue what the problem is and I really need any help from anyone much appreciated !!!

The github for the DYDX API python package
https://github.com/dydxprotocol/dydx-v3-python

pip install dydx-v3-python

[image]

[image]

if I do print(candles) i get
<dydx3.helpers.requests.Response object at 0x00000192EA879C90>
in the terminal

Here are the API docs for DYDX exchange
https://dydxprotocol.github.io/v3-teacher/?python#get-candles-for-market

```
import asyncio, json, time, websockets
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

from dydx3 import Client
from dydx3.helpers.request_helpers import generate_now_iso
from web3 import Web3
from dydx3.constants import *



# Access public API endpoints.
client = Client(
    host='https://api.dydx.exchange',
)
client.public.get_markets()

price=client.public.get_candles(MARKET_BTC_USD, resolution="5MINS")
print(price)

candles = client.public.get_candles(
  market=MARKET_BTC_USD,
  resolution='1DAY',
)
candles
```

Comment: If you want to print the value of `candles`, you need to use `print(candles)`.

Comment: if I do print(candles) i get <dydx3.helpers.requests.Response object at 0x00000192EA879C90>   in the terminal do you know what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is print(candles.data)

[image]

Comment: thanks, this was driving me crazy too. Why don't they put it in the documentation?!